# Is there an alternative for deprecated rdf4j JSONLDSettings?

Tags: rdf4j

i was just happy to have found [HIERARCHICAL_VIEW](https://rdf4j.org/javadoc/2.5.4/org/eclipse/rdf4j/rio/helpers/JSONLDSettings.html#HIERARCHICAL_VIEW) and then disappointed that it is deprecated. is there an alternative for the configuration of jsonld writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by [this GH pull request](https://github.com/eclipse-rdf4j/rdf4j/pull/4332) and [its related issue](https://github.com/eclipse-rdf4j/rdf4j/issues/1755), they will just be moved to a different package/module in 5.0.0. So no need to worry about the class being removed altogether.

Comment: Ahh, cool!! Thanks when I see deprecated, my head peels off ;-) And JSONLDSettings is not in the 'old' version, so i didn't see it.